# In "with which [subject] engaged with", why does 1 of the with's feel redundant?

Tags: redundancy

I know that BOTH **with**'s below are necessary, because they are required in my rewrites below. But when I see 2 **with**'s in the relative clause "**with<sub>1</sub>**  which [subject] engaged **with<sub>2</sub>**", these 2 **with**'s still appear superfluous to me! I still feel that one can be deleted without losing meaning. Why? Can someone please help me overcome this psycholinguistic or optical illusion?

They engaged **with<sub>2</sub>** us **with<sub>1</sub>** enthusiasm. ⟸

> Along the way, they invited other artists along with them, and we are very grateful for the enthusiasm **with<sub>1</sub>** which they engaged **with<sub>2</sub>** us.

Máiréad Enright, *Northern / Irish Feminist Judgments* 2017, [p 18](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Northern_Irish_Feminist_Judgments/9mQHDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22with+which+they+engaged+with%22&pg=PA18&printsec=frontcover) last sentence.

You engaged **with<sub>2</sub>** this book **with<sub>1</sub>** enthusiasm. ⟸

> Thank you for the care **with<sub>1</sub>**  which you engaged **with<sub>2</sub>** this book[,] and the detailed and generative feedback you offered twice over.

Nicole Charles, *Suspicion
Vaccines, Hesitancy, and the Affective Politics of Protection in Barbados*, [Acknowledgements, 1st of 2 pages, but n. pag. (](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Suspicion/ei5LEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22with+which+you+engaged+with%22&pg=PT5&printsec=frontcover).

I engaged  **with<sub>2</sub>** my Tanzanian texts **with<sub>1</sub>** the toolkit [that] was 'outstanding in its usefulness and clarity [...]'. ⇐

> The toolkit **with<sub>1</sub>**  which I engaged  **with<sub>2</sub>** my Tanzanian texts in the 1980s was outstanding in its usefulness and clarity—we had standard "recipes," so to speak, for doing the work of political discourse analysis. ⟸

Christian W. Chun, *Applied Linguistics and Politics* 2022, [p. 30](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Applied_Linguistics_and_Politics/J5RZEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22with+which+i+engaged+with%22&pg=PA30&printsec=frontcover)

He engaged **with<sub>2</sub>** the new Conrad project **with<sub>1</sub>** with the energy indicated[d] [in] Loerke's later diary. ⟸

> Loerke's later diary entries indicate the energy **with<sub>1</sub>**  which he engaged  **with<sub>2</sub>** the new Conrad project.

Anthony Fothergill, *Secret Sharers
Joseph Conrad's Cultural Reception in Germany* 2006, [p. 31](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Secret_Sharers/bFB9iXgo9-0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22with+which+he+engaged+with%22&pg=PA31&printsec=frontcover).

> Second, the overall frequency **with<sub>1</sub>**  which he engaged  **with<sub>2</sub>** both terms increased significantly after the mid-1970s.

Thomas Lemke, *The Government of Things
Foucault and the New Materialisms* 2021, [p 105](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/The_Government_of_Things/d3EnEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22with+which+he+engaged+with%22&pg=PA105&printsec=frontcover).

> Despite shortcomings in the narratives of Hastings Neville and Augustus Hare, they provide the best available insights into Waterford's philanthropic activity, and into the unaffected manner — contrary to the standards of the era — **with<sub>1</sub>**  which she engaged  **with<sub>2</sub>** her tenantry and the poor.

Caroline Ings-Chambers, *Louisa Waterford and John Ruskin* 2017, [p 195](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Louisa_Waterford_and_John_Ruskin/LS8rDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22with+which+she+engaged+with%22&pg=PA195&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Do you mean: why 2 *with*?

Comment: Don't do this:  `with's`. - You must not use a possessive apostrophe for a plural. You are allowed to use a plural form of a preposition (such as 'with') when discussing the word itself e.g. I counted five ands, six buts and two withs in one sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both necessary. One **with** attaches to **engage**. The other attaches to **enthusiasm, care, toolkit**, etc.

What you are experiencing is a rejection of the style, not the grammar. And I feel your pain. The sentences *sound* awkward. If I were writing them, I would revise to eliminate the repetition. My instinct would be to replace **engage with,** I think. It has a trendy, psychobabble quality that I dislike.

Comment: Thanks! " And I feel your pain. The sentences *sound* awkward." Can you please elaborate? Why exactly? I just fancy pinpointing the root of my pain. "It has a trendy, psychobabble quality that I dislike." Please elaborate? What's this "trendy, psychobabble quality"?

Comment: The repetition sounds awkward. As to the other, in normal conversation, we don't usually speak of people **engaging with** things. It's the kind of thing I expect an incompetent department manager to say when they have returned to the office with "fresh ideas" from a management conference. But that's a rather subjective statement.